# Power BI - comparing row value with column from another table results in excessive computational load

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I'm analyzing the logs from a firewall and I wanted to add two columns in Power Query M to determine if either the source or the destination ip address are LAN addresses or from the Internet.

I created a file called Private_IPs.txt that contains row by row all the internal subnets (10. , 172.16., 172.17. etc) and loaded it as a table.

The code for the calculation is this:

```
#"Add dst isPrivate" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add src isPrivate", "dst_isPrivate", each List.Count(let tmp_dst = [dest_ip] in List.Select(Table.Column(Private_IPs, "Subnet"), each Text.StartsWith(tmp_dst, _))))
```

1. It creates a list by selecting the column `"Subnet"` of the table `Private_IPs`
2. From this lists, it only keeps the element that `[dest_ip]` starts with, if any.
3. It then counts the numbers of items in the filtered list, so that my resulting column value is either 0 or 1

It works but the problem is that when I Refresh the data, it loads the file "PrivateIPs.csv" two times for each row of the table, resulting in minutes and minutes of loading time and the counter reports something like

> "10MB from Private_IPs.csv"

> "20MB from Private_IPs.csv"

[...]

> "400MB from Private_IPs.csv"

Why does this happen? Shouldn't it keep the table in memory instead of reading from the file each time? How do I make it so? It's only a text file with 17 rows in it, maybe my solution is too convoluted?

Answer (score 0):

Since the table with the private subnets was very small and it won't change, I created it manually inside the Query Editor and it's now only loading once.

Comment: Another solution cloud be Table.Buffer